# Should I use a singleton for my console game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing my first time in python - a console game. I reached the point where I have to make the decision wheter I should use singletons or not.

**The situation:**

I have classes like (for example) Character. If you begin a new game, character creation starts (name your character, ...)

After creating a character, I create an object from Character class `character = Character(name, foo, bar`)

**The problem:**

When I need the character obj in other functions / classes later (for example to save it to a json file), I have to get access to the initially created object. **I will never need multiple player objects**

Now I'm wondering if i should use singleton(s) or if i should always pass my object to places where I need it. Another option would be to store variables in a module and import the module if i need to get data.

So what do you think?

Comment: *"I will never need multiple player objects"* One thing I've learned about requirements is that they change even if you don't expect them to, so never say never. Is it really unthinkable that you'll add a multiplayer mode someday?

Comment: Maybe you need a class (Game ?) that contains references to everything (characters,...).

Comment: "After creating a character, I create an object from Character class" — you won't have created a character _until_ you've called the `Character` class to create an instance. If the class is implemented as a singleton, it would return the same instance each time vs a new, different ones. Whether the class is implemented as a singleton or not would really affect the rest of your coding (just behavior if any attempts are made to create more than one instance).

Comment: Singletons can interfere with stuff like automated testing and parallel programming. And you can mimic their behavior just with module level variables. Singletons are designed for more restrictive languages and there is no real need to use them in python,

Comment: @Aran-Fey I know. Even if I really will never need multiple objects here, I like to design things in a way to maintain flexibility :)

Comment: @Jérôme Yeah, do you mean, that that class should be a singleton? Right now I'm starting to like the approach of a "game" module that holds (for example) a player variable - is that what you mean?

Comment: You are writing a simple game. Don't overcomplicate things! Using singleton is overcomplicating things. Just go with a global variable storing player object! Once your game is complete, then consider how you would avoid the global state, or how you would wrap the global state to make using it thread safe, etc. Don't get bogged down by doing things "right" in your *first* Python project. Time for better Python programming practices comes in the next projects.

Comment: @AGuyAskingQuestions, I meant a Game class instantiated once at application startup. And like others said, I wouldn't bother enforcing singleton-ness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Zen of Python,

> Simple is better than complex.

One way to have only one player object is to create some sort of singleton pattern that forcibly restricts multiple players. A simpler way to accomplish the same goal is to just not instantiate a second player.

If you do want to force a singleton pattern for whatever reason (e.g. accessing the same character from multiple places), a module is far and away the best way to accomplish that effect. The syntax is easy to use, modules are easily accessible from an entire project, and any essential singleton machinery is already built-in to the module semantics.

Comment: Right now I solved my problem by storing variables in a "game" module. So everytime I need my player object access it with `game.player`. Is that what you recommend?

Comment: Nothing about that raises red flags to me. Above anything else though, I'd just build it with whatever constructs come naturally to you and see what works. It's hard to plan for every eventuality, but it's usually fairly easy to examine how a piece of code fits with the rest of the project and determine whether it belongs or not, and you'll get a better game faster. Plus, if your goal from this is just to have a learning experience, you'll learn more from trying multiple approaches and failing a few times than you ever will by only having successes.